# How do I go about doing Egger's test for publication bias in a meta-analysis?

Tags: publication-bias

Hi my background is clinical medicine (not statistics). I have just done a meta-analysis of 41 randomized controlled trials of the effectiveness of antibiotics vs. placebo in preventing wound infection. I used Review Manager 5.3 software for the  data analysis (dichotomous data, random effects model), calculated the effect estimates as Odds Ratios (with 95% CI), and have already constructed a funnel plot within Revman for  publication bias.  I was then advised to do Egger's test to more accurately assess publication bias. There is no facility for that in Revman, does anyone know of an (inexpensive or free) stats program I can use? I am not sure how to do it 'by hand', but will try if not too complex.  Any Advice welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use the free statistical software R ([link](https://www.r-project.org/)). I generally use the `metafor` package, but there are also other packages out there that can be used for this purpose (see [this page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MetaAnalysis.html) for more information about R packages related to meta-analysis).

An example using the `metafor` package:

```
install.packages("metafor") # Install metafor package

library(metafor) # Load metafor package

dat <- dat.bangertdrowns2004 # Use these data as example

res <- rma(yi = yi, vi = vi, data = dat) # Random-effects meta-analysis

regtest(res) # Conduct Egger's test

Regression Test for Funnel Plot Asymmetry

model:     mixed-effects meta-regression model
predictor: standard error

test for funnel plot asymmetry: z = 2.4904, p = 0.0128
```

`?regtest # Description of the function in the metafor package`

It might be important to realize that the `rma()` function by default uses the restricted maximum likelihood estimator (REML) for estimating the between-study variance in a meta-analysis. If Review Manager is using a different estimator for the between-study variance, you may also get slightly different results. You can, however, specify the estimator for the between-study variance in the `rma()` function. See `?rma` for more information.